# Pandas dataframe rows incorrectly dropping when one condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

**Background:**
I have a pandas `df` which I am trying to remove rows from if the following conditions are **all met**.

- `% Ownership` *(float64)* == 100
- `Ownership Audit Note` (object) contains either 'Ignore' or 'ignore'
- `Entity ID %` *(float64)* == `Account # %` *(object)*

**Issue** - it looks like my code is dropping rows if any conditions is met, rather than all of them. Is there something wrong with my code?

**My current code:** this is the line of code I wrote -

```
df = df[(~(df['Ownership Audit Note'].str.contains('ignore|Ignore')))
& (~(df['% Ownership'] == 100))
& (~(df['Entity ID %'] == 'Account # %'))]
```

**Extract from `df`**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "% Ownership": {0: 100.0, 1: 50.0, 2: 100.0},
        "Ownership Audit Note": {
            0: "[ignore] 100% Ownership ",
            1: "[Ignore] 50% Ownership ",
            2: "[ignored] Recurring 67% as of 2022-01-07 ",
        },
        "Entity ID %": {
            0: 100.0,
            1: 50.0,
            2: 67.0,
        },
        "Account # %": {
            0: 100.0,
            1: 50.0,
            2: 65.0,
        },
    }
)
```

**How my code is currently behaving:** using my current code at the `db` extract as an example.

- Index position 0 - the first row should drop (and is) as all conditions are met.
- Index position 1 - this row should not drop as `% Ownership` is not == 100. This row is still dropping.
- Index position 2 - this row should not drop as `Entity ID %` does not == `Account # %`. This row is still dropping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invert the final result of the **and**, not each invert each test (or then you'd need to use **or**). Also there was a mistake, you were comparing `df['Entity ID %']` to a fixed string:

```
df[~(df['Ownership Audit Note'].str.contains('ignore|Ignore')
     & df['% Ownership'].eq(100)
     & df['Entity ID %'].eq(df['Account # %'])
     )]
```

output:

```
   % Ownership                       Ownership Audit Note  Entity ID %  Account # %
1         50.0                    [Ignore] 50% Ownership          50.0         50.0
2        100.0  [ignored] Recurring 67% as of 2022-01-07          67.0         65.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[(df['Ownership Audit Note'].str.contains('ignore', case=False))
&(df['% Ownership'] == 100.0)
&(df['Entity ID %'] == df['Account # %'])]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

As you said correctly, the problem is that you are keeping only rows that match every condition. This is because you use the NOT operator (`~`) on each condition and not on the sum of them all. This will first find the rows in which all conditions are met, and then take the opposite rows:

```py
df = df[(~(df['Ownership Audit Note'].str.contains('ignore|Ignore'))
& (df['% Ownership'] == 100)
& (df['Entity ID %'] == 'Account # %'))]
```

Comment: I have either misunderstood your response or there has been some confusion. I am trying to drop rows from `df` that meet all of the 3x conditions stipulated above, not the opposite. Your suggested code drops rows where any of the 3x conditions are matched